# How build and run samples

Tags: flutter

In the futter/examples folder there are lot examples of applications. How to build and run them on Android for instance? I tried to open projects using the IntelliJ IDEA framework, but I did not succeed. I.e. the project is being opened, but it's impossible to build it because of undecidable dependences.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
flutter update-packages
```

then in the directory of the example

```
flutter run
```